# In R, can I concatenate, then call variable column=concatenated string?

Tags: r, concatenation

I am trying to identify the time of primary ambulance arrival for a number of patients in my dataframe=`data`.

The primary ambulance is either the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th vehicle on scene (`data$prim.amb.num=1`, `2`, `3`, or `4` for each patient/row).

`data$time_v1`, `data$time_v2`, `data$time_v3` and `data$time_v4` have a time or a missing value, which corresponds to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th vehicles, where relevant.

What I would like to do is make a new variable=`prim.amb.time` with the time that corresponds to primary ambulance arrival time. Suppose for patient=1, the ambulance was the first. Then I want `data[1,"prim.amb.time"]=data[1,"time_v1"]`.

I can figure out the correct `time_v*` with the following:

```
paste("time_v", data$prim.amb.num, sep="")
```

But I'm stuck as to how to pass the resulting information to call the correct column.

My hope was to simply have something like:

```
data$prim.amb.time<-data$paste("time_v", data$prim.amb.num, sep="")
```

but of course, this doesn't work. I'm not even sure how to Google for this; I tried various combinations of this title but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post `dput(data)`, or perhaps `dput(data[1:10, ])`, so that we can reproduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I liked the answer by @mhermans, if you want a one-liner, one solution is to use `?apply` as follows:

```
#From @mhermans
zz <- textConnection("patient.id prime.amb.num time_v1 time_v2 time_v3 time_v4
1000 1 30 40 60 100 
1001 3 40 50 60 80
1002 2 10 30 40 45
1003 1 24 40 45 60
")
d <- read.table(zz, header = TRUE)
close(zz)

#Take each row of d and pull out time_vn where n = d$prime.amb.num
d$prime.amb.time <- apply(d, 1, function(x) {x[x['prime.amb.num'] + 2]})

> d
  patient.id prime.amb.num time_v1 time_v2 time_v3 time_v4 prime.amb.time
1       1000             1      30      40      60     100             30
2       1001             3      40      50      60      80             60
3       1002             2      10      30      40      45             30
4       1003             1      24      40      45      60             24
```

EDIT - or with `paste`:

```
d$prime.amb.time <- 
  apply(
    d, 
    1, 
    function(x) {
      x[paste('time_v', x['prime.amb.num'], sep = '')]
    }
  )
#Gives the same result
```

Comment: It took me a second to see where the `+2` came from, that is a nice oneliner.

Comment: Thanks, lockedoff. I actually ended up doing something like this with plyr. However, my function was not one line so thank you for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Set up example data:

```
# read in basic example data for four patients, wide format
zz <- textConnection("patient.id prime.amb.num time_v1 time_v2 time_v3 time_v4
1000 1 30 40 60 100 
1001 3 40 50 60 80
1002 2 10 30 40 45
1003 1 24 40 45 60
")
d <- read.table(zz, header = TRUE)
close(zz)
```

In the example dataset I'm thus assuming your data looks like this:

```
  patient.id prime.amb.num time_v1 time_v2 time_v3 time_v4
1       1000             1      30      40      60     100
2       1001             3      40      50      60      80
3       1002             2      10      30      40      45
4       1003             1      24      40      45      60
```

Given that data structure, it is perhaps easier to work with a dataset with a vehicle per row, instead of a patient per row. This can be accomplised by using `reshape()` to convert from a wide to a long format.

```
dl <- reshape(d, direction='long', idvar="patient.id", varying=list(3:6))
# ordering & rename var for aesth. reasons:
dl <- dl[order(dl$patient.id, dl$time),]
dl$vehicle.id <- dl$time 
dl$time <- NULL
dl
```

This gives a long dataset, with a row per vehicle:

```
       patient.id prime.amb.num time_v1 vehicle.id
1000.1       1000             1      30          1
1000.2       1000             1      40          2
1000.3       1000             1      60          3
1000.4       1000             1     100          4
1001.1       1001             3      40          1
1001.2       1001             3      50          2
1001.3       1001             3      60          3
1001.4       1001             3      80          4
1002.1       1002             2      10          1
1002.2       1002             2      30          2
1002.3       1002             2      40          3
1002.4       1002             2      45          4
1003.1       1003             1      24          1
1003.2       1003             1      40          2
1003.3       1003             1      45          3
1003.4       1003             1      60          4
```

Getting the arrival time of the first ambulance per patient then become a simple oneliner:

```
dl[dl$prime.amb.num == dl$vehicle.id,]
```

which gives

```
       patient.id prime.amb.num time_v1 vehicle.id
1000.1       1000             1      30          1
1001.3       1001             3      60          3
1002.2       1002             2      30          2
1003.1       1003             1      24          1
```

Comment: +1 for finding the right parameters for reshape/base. reshape man page is the only printout of a function I have on my table, because I never get it without.